# CSS vs jQuery | is it possible to hide/show div inside a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Show class-A alone (at the top of the page) while all other (x,x,c) are hidden.
Hide class-A alone while all other (x,x,c) are shown.

Is this possible ?

```
<div class="x">
    <div class="y">
        <div class="z"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="A">
    <div class="y">
        <div class="z"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="x">
    <div class="w">
        <div class="q"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="C">
    <div class="p">
        <div class="s"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Would be better if the code is only with class-A
(Without including other classes(x,c)). Because these may change dynamically.

I tried this: http://jsfiddle.net/smilyface/qX546/

Comment: Please add your javascript/jquery code.

Comment: use $(".classname").show() and  $(".classname").hide()

Comment: Downvoters are advised to comment on the reason for downvoting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use,

```
var a=$("div.A");
var others=$("div").not(".A,.A div");
a.toggle();
others.toggle();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nveua/)

Answer (score 1):

you can check like this

```
if($('.A').is(":visible")){
  $('.A').hide();
  $("div:not('.A')").show();
}else if($("div:not('.A')").is(':visible')){

}
```

may this help you

Comment: Will the $("div:not('.A')") effect Y and Z inside A ?

Comment: i think yes. i just gave you an idea you can modify the code according to your need :)

Comment: Ravi, i tried. It doesn't work as per my need. But thanx for div:not code :) http://jsfiddle.net/smilyface/qX546/

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with toggle but first you have to hide A class on page load:

```
$('.A').hide();

$('#button').click(function(){
    $('.A').toggle();
    $('.x').toggle();
    $('.C').toggle();
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pq23M/)

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap the three DIVs (a,x,c) in one outer DIV.

```
<div class="x">
</div>
<div class="outer">
    <div class="A">
    </div>
    <div class="x">
    </div>
    <div class="C">
    </div>
</div>
```

You can set `.outer` to `display:none` initially in your CSS definition.

```
.outer { display: none; }
```

You can then use jQuery to call `$('.x').toggle()` and `$('.outer').toggle()`.

An even easier way would be to add a classname to both DIVs and call `toggle()` once on that class.

```
<div class="x toggleMe">
</div>
<div class="toggleMe" style="display:none;">
    <div class="A">
    </div>
    <div class="x">
    </div>
    <div class="C">
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.toggleMe').toggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

this is absolutely possible,

First give display:none; as default for class a, and nothing for rest of your classes,

and toggle the both using jquery.

like

```
//in css
.A {
   display: none;
 }

//in js

$('.A').toggle();
$('.X,.C').toggle();
```